# Components.classes ERROR - FireFox Add-On(Extension) in VS 2013

Tags: javascript, c#, visual-studio-2013, firefox-addon

I want to check javascript codes of a firefox add-on(extension) in visual studio 2013.
I am c# web developer and so i created an empty web application project with c# language and created a new webform(Default.aspx) in that project and put those javascript codes in there.
Here is the example  :

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
      const Cc = Components.classes, Ci = Components.interfaces;
      var clazz = Cc["@mozilla.org/messenger;1"];
  </script>
```

But after open Default.aspx in firefox browser i got the error below :

> The Components object is deprecated. It will soon be removed.
>   Cc is undefined.

How can i solve those errors?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This indicates that your code is not running as an add-on. Instead it is running as a normal "content" web page. In normal content pages, Components is deprecated but not in an add-on.

If you just want to experiment with occasional bits of code you might want to use the browser toolbox to open a scratchpad and stay away from Visual Studio entirely:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Browser_Toolbox

Otherwise, you should do some more reading about how to start building an add-on:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons

And if you want to see an example of an addon being developed in Visual Studio, you could take a look at KeeFox:

https://github.com/luckyrat/KeeFox/

The bulk of the code you'd be interested in would be in this folder hierarchy:

https://github.com/luckyrat/KeeFox/tree/master/Firefox%20addon

Spoiler alert: Don't use .aspx or C# :-)